# How to add Selectone row to a drop down list using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a table called States and i am displaying values of states in a dropdown list using linq query
Now i want to insert selection on the first place of id 0.
I am using following query to display dropdown list:

```
var str = (from li in dbContext.states

               where li.state >= 1
               select new
               {

                   a=li.state

               }).ToArray();
```

The above query gives mean all the values present in my DB.How can i insert select one at first place?
Any one please suggest any method or syntax.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See MajoBs answer.

Although if you're using the `@Html.DropDownListFor()`  Helper, you could also specify the Id 0 row using the optionLabelArgument:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    string optionLabel
)
```

**Update:**

I think the reason  MajoB's example doesn't work is because you are using an anonymous type in the Linq query, but define a string in the `.Insert()` statement.

I believe it is not possible to reuse the same anonymous type that was used in the LINQ query in the `.Insert()` statement.

So you would have to use a regular type.

```
(from x in 
    (from li in dContext.states
    where li.state >= 0
        select new {
            value = li.state,
            text = li.something
        }).AsEnumerable()
    select new SelectListeItem {
        Value = x.value.ToString()
        Text = x.text
    }).ToList().Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { .. });
```

The nested query is necessary because the `.ToString()` can't be translated to sql. The `.AsEnumerable()` call created an in-memory list where `.ToString` will work on.

I am actually using a Extension method like this in our code base.
But it requires [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to work.

```
public static IList<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IQueryable<T> query
        , Expression<Func<T, long>> value
        , Expression<Func<T, string>> text
        , string nullText = null)
    {
        var result = (from x in
                          (from y in query.AsExpandable()
                           select new
                           {
                               Value = value.Invoke(y),
                               Text = text.Invoke(y),
                           }).AsEnumerable()
                      select new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Value = x.Value.ToString(),
                          Text = x.Text.ToString()
                      }).ToList();

        AddNullText(nullText, result);
        return result;
    }

private static void AddNullText(string nullText, List<SelectListItem> result)
    {
        if (nullText != null)
        {
            result.Insert(0, new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = "",
                Text = nullText,
            });
        }
    }
```

(+ the same Extension method with `Expression<Func<T, string>>`, etc.. as second parameter.)

Comment: :I tried MajoB answer but i am error stating that "Method has some invalid arguments".And i need to add this "Select One" in id 0 row using linq query.Is there any other possible way

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one extra item to the beginning of the list.

```
var str = (from li in dbContext.states

               where li.state >= 1
               select new
               {

                   a=li.state

               }).ToList().Insert(0, "selectone");
```

Comment: :I used the above method it is stating that "There are some invalid arguments"

Comment: Sorry...I am selecting two values here,one is li.state which is string and other is li.Id which is integer.